# How to get a value from optarg

Tags: c, getopt

Hi I am writing a simple client-server program. In this program I have to use `getopt()` to get the port number and ip address like this:

server -i 127.0.0.1 -p 10001

I do not know how can I get values from optarg, to use later in the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about like this:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE+1];
snprintf(buf,BUFSIZE,"%s",optarg);
```

Or in a more complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 16

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char c;
    char port[BUFSIZE+1];
    char addr[BUFSIZE+1];

    while(( c = getopt( argc, argv, "i:p:" )) != -1 )
        switch ( c )
        {
            case 'i':
                snprintf( addr, BUFSIZE, "%s", optarg );
                break;
            case 'p':
                snprintf( port, BUFSIZE, "%s", optarg );
                break;
            case '?':
                fprintf( stderr, "Unrecognized option!\n" );
                break;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

For more information see the documentation of [Getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Comment: The answer using strdup is a better solution to this problem.  It avoids creating a fixed-size buffer for an unknown length string

Answer (score 17):

You use a while loop to move through all the arguments and process them like so ...

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int option = -1;
    char *addr, *port;

    while ((option = getopt (argc, argv, "i:p:")) != -1)
    {
         switch (option)
         {
         case 'i':
             addr = strdup(optarg);
             break;
         case 'p':
             port = strdup(optarg);
             break;
         default:
              /* unrecognised option ... add your error condition */
              break;
         }
    }

    /* rest of program */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strdup` causes memory leak if you don't free them before you exit. So in your example, you need to free `addr` and `port`.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of the numerous flaws of the getopt documentation: it does not state clearly that optarg must be copied for later use (using strdup(), for instance) because it may be overwritten by later options or just plain freed by getopt.

Comment: from getopt docs, http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html: ..."You don't ordinarily need to copy the optarg string, since it is a pointer into the original argv array, not into a static area that might be overwritten."

Comment: @dmityugov - that may be true, but I would generally frown upon solutions that take advantage of inner knowledge of the implementation. The code can be made much more robust at small cost by duplicating the string into memory under the programmer's control rather than the library's control.

Comment: A pointer into argv is not safe, because "The default is to permute the contents of argv while scanning it so that eventually all the non-options are at the end.", meaning the contents of argv changes as options is called repeatedly. If the permutations are all done by the time options returns the first time, then the doc ought to state so.

Comment: @tvanfosson It is not inner knowledge of the implementation , it is documented behavior - even the official [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) gives code examples that depends on that behavior. @ Urhixidur the permutation does not change the location of the strings, it just reporders the pointers within argv to those strings.

Comment: @nos The pointed strings may not change, but the values in the argv array do, which is not something one ordinarily expects.

Comment: @Urhixidur Sure - but that doesn't affect taking a copy of the optarg pointer, that copy will point to proper string, which will not be changed or reordered.  What you describe would be an issue if you stored e.g. the argv index, or optind.

Comment: @nos Getting back to the original dmityugov statement extracted from the getopt documentation, optarg is described as "a pointer into the original argv array". This is an array of pointers. As you state, the strings pointed to by the array do not change, but since the argv array itself gets reorganised by permutations, optarg will change unexpectedly. The doc is thus incorrect either because optarg actually points to the string pointed to by argv, or optarg does change (and one thus needs to copy its target or target reference).

Comment: @Urhixidur I still disagree with that, if optarg was a pointer to an element in the argv array, it would have a type of  `char **` , but it is a `char *`. optarg demonstrably points to one of the strings pointed to by an argv element. (Those strings again are all stored in a contiguous piece of memory in glibc, and I suspect that contiguous char array is what the those glibc docs refer to when it states "original argv array", it does not refer to the array of pointers that is the argument of main() )

Comment: @nos I think we can both agree at this point that the description in the doc is ambiguous: "a pointer into the original argv array" can be understood in several mutually incompatible ways.

Comment: Urhixidur, I disagree. Not only @nos argument is correct, "a pointer into the original argv array" is one of the pointers **in there** (_into_), not a pointer **to** a pointer that's in there, as you have reasoned. The original argv is a set of pointers, the mutated argv is the same set of pointers, just reordered along the way. If you copy any pointer at the start of the process, the permutation of argv won't mean nothing for the values pointed to by those reordered pointers. And as the official docs states, and as the examples show, all points out there's no need for strdup.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an ip and port you don't need to store the strings. Just parse them and store the values in a sockaddr.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>                  // for inet_ntop, inet_pton                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <getopt.h>                     // for getopt, optarg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <netinet/in.h>                 // for sockaddr_in, etc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <stdio.h>                      // for fprintf, printf, stderr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <stdlib.h>                     // for atoi, EXIT_SUCCESS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <string.h>                     // for memset                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <sys/socket.h>                 // for AF_INET                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    struct sockaddr_in sa;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    char c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    sa.sin_port = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:p:")) != -1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        switch (c)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            case 'p':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                sa.sin_port = htons(atoi(optarg));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            case 'i':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                inet_pton(AF_INET, optarg, &(sa.sin_addr));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            case '?':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        } /* -----  end switch  ----- */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    printf("%s:%d\n", str, ntohs(sa.sin_port));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
} /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```