# What is the easiest way to parse arguments from a file in C?

Tags: c, file, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

Consider a file `ArgumentFile.txt`

```
int a=100;
int b[3] = { 5, 2, 5 };
double c = 0.0014;
```

And the main code `code.c`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc > 1) FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   ParseFile(f); // Set the parameters based on file
   DoStuff(a,b,c); // Run the process based on the parsed arguments
}
```

A user could then pass arguments by doing

```
./CodeExecutable ArgumentFile.txt
```

Is there a standard solution to parse arguments from file? It would be an equivalent of `getopt` which parse arguments from command line?

Comment: Note that `fopen(argv[1], "r")` and `Source(argv[1])` is _too easy_.  Should be `if (argc > 1) { FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); ...`

Comment: the `modern` way to get arguments from the command line is to use `getopt` or `getopt_long`.  See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973742/how-to-get-a-value-from-optarg

Comment: @bruceg Thanks! Is there an equivalent to `getopt` that would come handy not to parse command line arguments but arguments coming from a file?

Comment: @chux Thanks post edited!

Comment: The format of the input text file as C code variable declarations is entirely inconsistent with the rest of the question which suggest the file would contain the equivalent to command line arguments that could be processed by `getopts()`.

Comment: @Remi.b presumably if you redirect standard input to read from your file, you can use `getopt`.  e.g. `./CodeExecutable < ArgumentFile.txt`

Comment: @bruceg : That will not work; `getopt` does not read `stdin`, and redirection does not affect the content of `argv`.

Comment: @clifford my bad for posting without trying it out first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an *equivalent* to `getopt()` you can use exactly `getopt()`.  The `getopt()` function does not specifically process command line arguments; it will process any array of pointers to strings in the *style* of command line arguments.

```
#define MAX_ARGS 256
#define MAX_FILE_LEN 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if( argc > 1 )
   {
      FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if( f != 0 )
      {
         char fargs[MAX_FILE_LEN] = "" ;
         fread( fargs, 1, MAX_FILE_LEN, f ) ;

         // Build fargv from file content
         char* fargv[MAX_ARGS] ;
         int fargc = 0 ;

         fargv[fargc] = strtok( fargs, " \n\r" ) ;

         while( fargc < MAX_ARGS && fargv[fargc] != 0 )
         {
            fargc++ ;
            fargv[fargc] = strtok( 0, "\n\r" ) ;
         }

         // Process fargv using getopt()
         while( (char c = getopt( fargc, fargv, "a:b:c:")) != -1 )
         {
            switch( c )
            {
               ...
            }
         }
      }
   }

   ...

   return 0 ;
}
```

It is probably better to dynamically allocate `fargs` using teh actual file length, but the above is illustrative only.

Your input file might then look like:

```
-a 100
-b 5,2,5
-c 0.0014
```

The `getopt()` loop will then have to process the arguments as necessary - using `sscanf()` for example.

```
        switch( c )
        {
           case 'a' : sscanf( optarg, "%i", a ) ; break ;
           case 'b' : sscanf( optarg, "%i,%i,%i", b[0], b[1], b[2] ) ; break ;
           case 'c' : sscanf( optarg, "%f", c ) ; break ; 
        }

        DoStuff( a, b, c ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use getopt(). Here is an example that allows for some more flexibility. This example demonstrates how th handle for optional optarg and multiple optargs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void usage(void)
{
    printf("usage: \n"
           "This example demonstrates how to add flexibility to the traditional linux getopt()\n"
           "This help text is printed if the program is executed without arguments\n"
           "or with an invalid argument configuration.\n"
           "to view the help file run without arguments or with -h\n"
           "Oterwise the program accepts two options: -d, -u\n"
           "-d: can come with 0 or one option argument\n"
           "-u: can come with one or more option arguments\n"
           "try this to see the output:\n"
           "./test -d aaa -u ccc 4 \"quoted multi token string\" -d -u\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char data[101];
    int opt;

    memset(data, 0, 101);
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hd:u:t:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'h':
            usage();
            return 0;
        case 'd': // can accept 0 or 1 parameters
            if (optarg[0] == '-') { //not an optarg of ours...
                optind--;
                printf("option: -d. no tokens (another option follows)\n");
                break;
            }
            strncpy(data, optarg, 100);
            printf("option: -d. tokens: %s\n", data);
            break;
        case 'u': //can accept one or more parameters ...
            strncpy(data, optarg, 100);
            printf("option: -u. tokens: %s", data);
            //do we have more arguments for 'u'?
            while( optind <= argc && argv[optind][0] != '-') {
                strncpy(data, argv[optind], 100);
                printf(", %s", data);
                optind++;
            }
            printf(".\n");
            break;
        case ':': //this happens if we got an option which expects an arg without any optarg.
            if(optopt == 'd') {//lets allow a '-d' without its optarg
                printf("option: -d. no tokens\n");
                break;
            }
            //otherwise fall through to the default handler
        default: //covers ':' '?' for missing value,  '-h' for help, etc.
            printf("on error you get: opt=%c. optopt=%c opterr=%d\n", opt, optopt, opterr);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using plain C code. You'll have to write platform specific assembly language code to handle that.

Your best option is to use the C proprocessor.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#include "myfile.txt"
   // Do Stuff 
}
```

Having said that, I don't know what you would gain by that instead of putting the contents of `myfile.txt` in `main()` directly.

Comment: Obviously you *can* do that, you may just have to write a function or some code to do it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that he is not asking to do that; you have completely misunderstood the question I think.

Comment: @MDXF,  judging by the `source(argv[1]);` bit, the OP wants the equivalent of a `#include` statement of the C preprocessor. I am not sure what you are thinking of.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It was clearly my mistake. I removed the `source(argv[1]);` statement. This statement was mainly here to exemplify the type of output (or consequence rather in term of variable assignment) that is expected from the parsing function I am looking for.

Comment: @Remi.b, perhaps you could elaborate on the "Do stuff" part of your code.

Comment: The `DoStuff` refers to whatever process needs to be run based on the variables that has been set thanks to parsing the arguments from the file. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Remi.b, that's too vague, IMO. If you can be concrete, it will be easier to suggest something more useful.

Comment: @RSahu : The question seems entirely clear to me - he wants to process whitespace delimited strings contained in a file as if they had been passed on the command line.  I cannot fathom how *you* have interpreted the question in the way you have.

Comment: @Clifford, after seeing the OP's update, I am more convinced that the proprocessor route is his best bet. How else would you be able to call `DoStuff(a, b, c);`?

Comment: @RSahu : Ok, I see what you mean, but would argue that the format of the input text file as C code is entirely inappropriate and not consistent with the rest of the question which suggest the file would contain the equivalent to command line arguments.

Comment: @Clifford, finally we are in agreement. The OP needs to be clearer.

Comment: Your suggestion is not a solution, since if `myfile.txt` is changed, the code must be recompiled.